# how can a non empty string .charAt(0) return an empty string?

Tags: javascript, string, charat

I'm really puzzled by this one ... It's so unbelievable that I post a screen capture of the Chrome debugger:

[image]

I quickly wrote this function in a test to compare 2 base64 encoded strings (`a` might be shorter than `b`).
However it always return 0, as if the first characters were different.
And in fact they are : the first character `ca` of string `a` is correct, but for some mysterious reason the first `cb` of string `b` is empty !!! The string `b` looks correct, has a correct length (685 chars) and has the correct type `typeof(b) == 'string'`

The calling code (actually it's TypeScript) is this, in case it helps :

```
requestGET('qBandConfig.sql', { jobid: this.job.jobid }) // get the blob from db 
    .then(json => {
      const base64:string = json[0]['bandconfig'] // type enforced to make sure
      this.editor.setBands(base64)
        .then(() => {
          // test that we find the same blob when re-encoding
          const check:string = this.editor.getBandsBLOB()
          const diff = firstDiff(check, base64) // always return 0 ????
          if (diff > -1 && check[diff] !== '=')
            this.log.warning('encoded blob ', check, ' is different from decoded ', base64)
        })
    })
```

Comment: Are we supposed to find the problem in a screenshot? Compare the values in the debugger, extract a minimum set that fails and post them here, check for any "invisible" unicode characters (`console.log([...a.slice(0,2)])`), ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could contain a non-printable character such as the [Zero Width Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space), known in HTML as `&#8203;`. I am not sure what the Chrome Dev Tools would show in such a case; it might show nothing indeed.

Examine `cb.length`, if it is 0 then `cb` is empty, otherwise it's not empty (obviously) and then you can use `charCodeAt()` to find out what is there.

Example code with Zero Width Space character:

```js
var x = "​";
console.log("x === '" + x + "'");
console.log("x.length === " + x.length);
console.log("x.charCodeAt(0) === " + x.charCodeAt(0));
```

Comment: That's it, thanks a lot ! b.charCodeAt(0) returns 65520 ... No idea why, because the string comes from a 3rd party package for database, and I expected Chrome debugger to display at least a tofu, but at least the mystery is gone.